# How do I use an injected angular module's service in my app?

Tags: angularjs, module, angular-services

I'm venturing into injecting different angular modules into my app.  One module I created contains a service that I would like to inject into a controller.  Does anyone have a good explanation of how to do this?

My app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myModule']);
```

myModule which contains a service I want to inject:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .factory('coolService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
      // API calls
    }]);
```

An example of how to correctly inject 'coolService' into this controller would answer my question nicely:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    ...
  }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', 'coolService', function ($scope, coolService) {
   coolService.do...
 }]);
```

thats all...

Comment: as a follow-up:

If I load two modules ("myModule1" and "myModule2") and both contain a service named 'coolService'.  How do I inject each one?